# Flask + Cloud Datastore: Routes parameters capturing entity ids that have ancestral relationships

Tags: flask, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Google Cloud Datastore uses keys to identify and query `Entities`. This works well with the Flask.route's url parameters when querying for entities:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()

@app.route('/post/<post_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post(post_id):
    post = client.get(client.key('Post', post_id)) 
    return client
```

However, this only works if the `Post` key does not have any `ancestors`:

```
Key('Post', 'post123')
```

But what if the `Post` key actually has `ancestors`, like below?

```
Key('User', 'user123', 'Post', 'post123')
```

This means that the flask route will no longer handle `/post/<post_id>` since `post_id` along does not represent the entire entity.

What are the possible solutions to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Same as a directory file system, Entities are hierarchically structured in Cloud Datastore. This type of structure makes it neat when organizing your data.

From [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#comparison_with_traditional_databases):

The complete key identifying the entity consists of a sequence of kind-identifier pairs specifying its ancestor path and terminating with those of the entity itself:

> Category of object ->  **Kind**
>
> One object -> **Entity**
>
> Individual data for an object -> **Property**
>
> Unique ID for an object ->     **Key**

I believe that you can still use the same route but will need to tweak your code to firstly query the post ID that you are interested by using its ancestor path.

Here's the working code that I tried and that you can modify to adjust it to your needs.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from google.cloud import datastore
from markupsafe import escape

# Starting Datastore Client.
client = datastore.Client()

# Home page will do a redirect to the specified URL.
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect('/post/<post_id>', code=302)

# The URL that we are intestered in. 
@app.route('/post/<post_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile(post_id):

# Query the post ID using its ancestors. 

# Method is always 'GET' by default, I kept it 'GET' just for testing purposes.
if request.method == 'GET' and request.url == '<post_id>':
    return '{} is the post ID'.format(escape(post_id))
else:
    return '{} is the post ID'.format(escape(post_id))



# The actual Flask app.
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

While I know that this may not give you a straight answer, I believe it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Given the <post_id> of the child entity alone, how do you query its ancestor? Isn't this impossible?